# MATLAB/octave count number of operations (flops)

Tags: matlab, octave

Is it possible to report number of operations to evaluate for example matrix/matrix (dense or sparse) in MATLAB or octave.

Comment: I very highly doubt that you can get Matlab or Octave to do this because they are using LAPACK or the like to do this sort of thing which, as far as I know, don't have any options to output the number of operations used.

Comment: @Justin I thought there would be something like driy-run mode to only estimate operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it personally, but the [Lightspeed Matlab Toolbox](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/) claims to support flops counting. Apparently the `flops` command was a valid option in MATLAB up through version 5.

Comment: octave actually has it, but always returns 0 (empty Matlab compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can use profile to get the cpu time for an operation.