# How to count the FLOPS?

Tags: linux, performance, matlab, cpu, benchmarking

I run my program in parallel on a single server (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz). This server has 4 cores, each of which has additional hyper-thread, i.e., 8 cores/threads in total.

I found that when the degree of parallelism of my program is less than 4, it can obtain almost linear speedup (see the right figure). But, when greater than 4, the speedup is aggravated. So, I suspect that it is because of the FLoat point Unit. This server only have 4 float point units. I want to interpret my experiment results by counting the [FLOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) (FLoating-point Operations Per Second). So, how could I count the FLOPS? Are they any other ways to interpret this result? thanks

[image: Parallelization on a 8core/threads Server]

Here is my perf list:

```
afancy@ubuntu:$ perf list

List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):
  cpu-cycles OR cycles                               [Hardware event]
  instructions                                       [Hardware event]
  cache-references                                   [Hardware event]
  cache-misses                                       [Hardware event]
  branch-instructions OR branches                    [Hardware event]
  branch-misses                                      [Hardware event]
  bus-cycles                                         [Hardware event]
  stalled-cycles-frontend OR idle-cycles-frontend    [Hardware event]
  stalled-cycles-backend OR idle-cycles-backend      [Hardware event]
  ref-cycles                                         [Hardware event]

  cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
  task-clock                                         [Software event]
  page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
  context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
  cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
  minor-faults                                       [Software event]
  major-faults                                       [Software event]
  alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
  emulation-faults                                   [Software event]

  L1-dcache-loads                                    [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-stores                                   [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-store-misses                             [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-prefetches                               [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                          [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-loads                                    [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-prefetches                               [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-prefetch-misses                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-loads                                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-load-misses                                    [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-stores                                         [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-store-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-prefetches                                     [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-prefetch-misses                                [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-prefetches                                    [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-prefetch-misses                               [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  branch-loads                                       [Hardware cache event]
  branch-load-misses                                 [Hardware cache event]
  node-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  node-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  node-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  node-prefetches                                    [Hardware cache event]
  node-prefetch-misses                               [Hardware cache event]

  rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event descriptor]
  cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
   (see 'man perf-list' on how to encode it)

  mem:<addr>[:access]                                [Hardware breakpoint]
```

Followings are the results of `perf stat matlab -nodesktop -no jvm<main.m`:

```
======================Num. of cores/threads = 2======================


                 458223.935241 task-clock                #    0.999 CPUs utilized          
                        39,038 context-switches          #    0.085 K/sec                  
                            78 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
                       459,290 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
             1,598,967,197,448 cycles                    #    3.489 GHz                    
               <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
               <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
             3,052,651,880,341 instructions              #    1.91  insns per cycle        
               675,069,830,714 branches                  # 1473.231 M/sec                  
                 3,699,587,126 branch-misses             #    0.55% of all branches        

                 458.519712953 seconds time elapsed
------------------------------------------------------
     472493.757765 task-clock                #    0.999 CPUs utilized          
            40,231 context-switches          #    0.085 K/sec                  
                83 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           454,849 page-faults               #    0.963 K/sec                  
 1,648,754,575,728 cycles                    #    3.489 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 3,050,973,794,286 instructions              #    1.85  insns per cycle        
   674,701,101,539 branches                  # 1427.958 M/sec                  
     3,854,961,561 branch-misses             #    0.57% of all branches        

     472.810679033 seconds time elapsed

==============    Num. of cores/threads = 4 ==========================


         233673.870204 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
                20,265 context-switches          #    0.087 K/sec                  
                   110 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               248,922 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
       815,466,229,226 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
       <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
       <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
     1,528,487,784,122 instructions              #    1.87  insns per cycle        
       338,001,335,905 branches                  # 1446.466 M/sec                  
         1,878,625,642 branch-misses             #    0.56% of all branches        

         234.029335936 seconds time elapsed
---------------------------------------------
     231203.147937 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            20,028 context-switches          #    0.087 K/sec                  
                91 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           249,906 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
   806,862,892,981 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,525,844,491,295 instructions              #    1.89  insns per cycle        
   337,423,026,113 branches                  # 1459.422 M/sec                  
     1,839,223,079 branch-misses             #    0.55% of all branches        

     231.578239447 seconds time elapsed
 -----------------------------------------
      233813.938379 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            20,210 context-switches          #    0.086 K/sec                  
                78 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           246,951 page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
   815,974,334,825 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,525,890,625,730 instructions              #    1.87  insns per cycle        
   337,426,244,903 branches                  # 1443.140 M/sec                  
     1,981,754,037 branch-misses             #    0.59% of all branches        

     234.193620912 seconds time elapsed
-------------------------------------------------
     233269.315745 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            20,202 context-switches          #    0.087 K/sec                  
               112 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           230,240 page-faults               #    0.987 K/sec                  
   814,074,094,896 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,526,825,737,326 instructions              #    1.88  insns per cycle        
   337,639,762,266 branches                  # 1447.425 M/sec                  
     1,852,788,062 branch-misses             #    0.55% of all branches        

     233.642106982 seconds time elapsed     

====================== Num. of cores/threads = 6 ================


         232682.918326 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            22,109 context-switches          #    0.095 K/sec                  
                96 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           172,440 page-faults               #    0.741 K/sec                  
   811,991,238,956 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,019,407,910,404 instructions              #    1.26  insns per cycle        
   225,426,394,521 branches                  #  968.814 M/sec                  
     1,344,046,527 branch-misses             #    0.60% of all branches        

     233.124504147 seconds time elapsed
 ------------------------------------------    
       210835.066220 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            18,696 context-switches          #    0.089 K/sec                  
               107 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           173,955 page-faults               #    0.825 K/sec                  
   735,764,609,235 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,019,083,429,216 instructions              #    1.39  insns per cycle        
   225,355,627,333 branches                  # 1068.872 M/sec                  
     1,316,268,293 branch-misses             #    0.58% of all branches        

     211.323109113 seconds time elapsed
 ---------------------------------------------    
       179852.029353 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            15,465 context-switches          #    0.086 K/sec                  
               107 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           172,942 page-faults               #    0.962 K/sec                  
   627,644,775,747 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,017,482,864,797 instructions              #    1.62  insns per cycle        
   225,004,972,767 branches                  # 1251.056 M/sec                  
     1,255,067,791 branch-misses             #    0.56% of all branches        

     180.246118105 seconds time elapsed
---------------------------------------------     
     219614.665400 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            21,290 context-switches          #    0.097 K/sec                  
                90 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           170,882 page-faults               #    0.778 K/sec                  
   766,392,860,245 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,017,686,212,128 instructions              #    1.33  insns per cycle        
   225,049,868,367 branches                  # 1024.749 M/sec                  
     1,322,942,620 branch-misses             #    0.59% of all branches        

     220.092311263 seconds time elapsed
----------------------------------------------          
       176764.084715 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            15,282 context-switches          #    0.086 K/sec                  
                99 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           168,629 page-faults               #    0.954 K/sec                  
   616,874,157,735 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
 1,018,436,813,450 instructions              #    1.65  insns per cycle        
   225,214,699,712 branches                  # 1274.098 M/sec                  
     1,271,583,320 branch-misses             #    0.56% of all branches        

     177.198129682 seconds time elapsed   


========================   Num. of cores/threads = 8 ==================


         207252.104133 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            18,598 context-switches          #    0.090 K/sec                  
                99 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           144,037 page-faults               #    0.695 K/sec                  
   723,242,099,542 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   764,758,792,593 instructions              #    1.06  insns per cycle        
   169,108,788,865 branches                  #  815.957 M/sec                  
     1,068,941,156 branch-misses             #    0.63% of all branches        

     207.729752155 seconds time elapsed
 ----------------------------------------------  
      206174.337637 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            22,188 context-switches          #    0.108 K/sec                  
               118 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           132,956 page-faults               #    0.645 K/sec                  
   719,474,677,828 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   765,214,496,607 instructions              #    1.06  insns per cycle        
   169,211,117,316 branches                  #  820.719 M/sec                  
     1,039,836,842 branch-misses             #    0.61% of all branches        

     206.652707435 seconds time elapsed
 ----------------------------------------------  
      205240.082258 task-clock                #    0.989 CPUs utilized          
            44,991 context-switches          #    0.219 K/sec                  
               163 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           136,109 page-faults               #    0.663 K/sec                  
   716,133,704,444 cycles                    #    3.489 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   763,898,836,941 instructions              #    1.07  insns per cycle        
   168,924,070,103 branches                  #  823.056 M/sec                  
     1,066,021,420 branch-misses             #    0.63% of all branches        

     207.511466061 seconds time elapsed
 ----------------------------------------------  
      205016.856849 task-clock                #    0.989 CPUs utilized          
            44,386 context-switches          #    0.216 K/sec                  
               180 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           133,995 page-faults               #    0.654 K/sec                  
   715,351,228,880 cycles                    #    3.489 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   763,637,525,789 instructions              #    1.07  insns per cycle        
   168,860,189,098 branches                  #  823.641 M/sec                  
     1,056,980,771 branch-misses             #    0.63% of all branches        

     207.231704712 seconds time elapsed
 ----------------------------------------------  
      205388.150659 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            21,328 context-switches          #    0.104 K/sec                  
               103 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           135,843 page-faults               #    0.661 K/sec                  
   716,737,227,792 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   764,359,316,365 instructions              #    1.07  insns per cycle        
   169,023,595,573 branches                  #  822.947 M/sec                  
     1,045,914,789 branch-misses             #    0.62% of all branches        

     205.857635295 seconds time elapsed
 ----------------------------------------------  
      207178.729781 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            17,956 context-switches          #    0.087 K/sec                  
               105 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           137,996 page-faults               #    0.666 K/sec                  
   722,998,617,131 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   763,085,695,510 instructions              #    1.06  insns per cycle        
   168,733,709,256 branches                  #  814.435 M/sec                  
     1,052,517,264 branch-misses             #    0.62% of all branches        

     207.608998891 seconds time elapsed
 ----------------------------------------------  
      206701.393252 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
            24,596 context-switches          #    0.119 K/sec                  
               137 cpu-migrations            #    0.001 K/sec                  
           136,553 page-faults               #    0.661 K/sec                  
   721,294,495,478 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   764,246,861,748 instructions              #    1.06  insns per cycle        
   168,997,611,020 branches                  #  817.593 M/sec                  
     1,050,078,827 branch-misses             #    0.62% of all branches        

     207.206805179 seconds time elapsed
 ----------------------------------------------  
          206455.394644 task-clock                #    0.997 CPUs utilized          
            26,089 context-switches          #    0.126 K/sec                  
                87 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           132,658 page-faults               #    0.643 K/sec                  
   720,429,194,133 cycles                    #    3.490 GHz                    
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
   764,339,875,802 instructions              #    1.06  insns per cycle        
   169,014,685,081 branches                  #  818.650 M/sec                  
     1,047,046,966 branch-misses             #    0.62% of all branches        

     206.982094466 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: You're likely not going to be able to count FLOPS using native Matlab code as it depends on many optimized libraries that take advantage of specific hardware (e.g., SIMD). You could try the toolbox [suggested in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2868526/2278029), but I don't know how reliable it is.

Comment: Have a read up on what hyperthreading is - You may have 2 hardware threads per core, but you still only have 1 FPU between them - for particularly intensive workloads, more than 4 threads may actually make things _slower_ due to context-switching.

Comment: you are correct, two hyperthreads per core. If you use the context-switching to interpret the speedup, but, why is the value of context-switch higher when I use two parallelism? ie, 39,038 context-switches and 40,231 context-switches

Comment: @afancy: Each core runs twice as much code which results in twice as much context-switches per core.